# How to completely remove flash from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, flash

I know Flash is the problem, how do I remove it from a Windows 7 computer completely?

Answer (score 2):

Start -> Control Panel -> Add or Remove -> Flash

Edit: you may have multiple "installs" of flash so there may be more than 1 thing to uninstall which has flash in it's title.

Comment: Also, there could be two flash installations. One for IE and one for Firefox compatible browsers. Make sure you get them both.

Comment: I recommend running this to be extra sure its gone. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html

Comment: @Joe Mako, did this solve the problem?  I'm wondering because the question is still open.